# MYSQL PHP Sorting table rows with Full date names by date

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have a table where there is a date field. 
The values of the items inserted there are full date names.

How will I be able to sort the selected result by proper date?

Example table

```
February 10, 2010
January 5, 2010
January 4, 2010
January 5, 2009
January 6, 2010
March 21, 2010
```

What I want to happen

```
January 5, 2009
January 4, 2010
January 5, 2010
January 6, 2010
February 10, 2010
March 21, 2010
```

Is there a mysql function for this?

Here is my query. Date field is named `date`

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `$table` ORDER BY date";
```

Unfortunately, this only sorts the result alphabetically. 
How should I modify/change the query?

Your future insights and feedback are greatly appreciated! :)

**UPDATE**

So the problem is that the field is `string/varchar`. Is it possible to change this after the data has been stored? And would the query above automatically sort it correctly?

Comment: that u have to know about database (table and fields) and its normalization ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the column in the database is setup as a `string`/`varchar`, versus a `datetime` field. There are a few ways to approach this, but the easiest would be to convert your fields to datetime fields instead.

An inefficient solution would be to do:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `$table` ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(`date`)";
```

This will convert your strings to dates, and then sort them, but will have to do this for every row in your database which could get cumbersome. Bottom line: If you're working with datetimes, use a `datetime` field.

Comment: Is it possible to change the field type after the datas are stored? And would it be automatically sorted by date if I used the query above?

Comment: I'm not too sure if this is possible, but rather to be safe than sorry, it's a fairly easy migration. First step, add a new field `datetime_temp` (a `datetime` field), then run a query: ``UPDATE `table` SET `datetime_temp` = STR_TO_DATE(`date`)``, ensure your data is correct in the db, drop the date field, and rename `datetime_temp` to `date`

Comment: Also, be sure to check out the [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function on how to retrieve the date formatted out of the database.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! So that is the purpose of the `date_format` function. I have encountered that during my research for this problem. I have to ask again, how would I add it to the query above? Example my date format is `DATE_FORMAT(date, '%M %e, %Y')` Is there anyway that I can add it to `$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY date";`?

Comment: ``SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%M %e, %Y') AS `date_formatted` FROM...``, then refer to that field in your array with `$row['date_formatted']`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store dates either as a datetime or timestamp field. I would recommend using a timestamp field, that way you can easily format it to whatever you want when retrieving it.